# RxJava Observable.Interval end emitting

Tags: rx-java, observable

I'd like to have repeating observable that emits items until some condition comes true. Then it calls onComplete and ends emitting.

I though that something like this would work, but I'm wrong:

```
return Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .flatMap(tick -> {
     if (condition) {
       return Observable.empty();
     }
     doSomething();
     return Observable.just(null);
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `takeUntil` :

```
  return Observable.interval(5, SECONDS)
                   .takeUntil(conditionObs)
                   .subscribe(t -> dosomething());
```

Please note that `conditionObs` (which is another observable) will have to emit something when the condition turn to be true.

you can check the doc here : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html

Comment: Yes, i came to takeWhile right after my question and it's working. TakeWhile does not need to be enother observable and suits my needs.